REST URL taxonomy when sensitive data passed in header
If I have a REST endpoint such as /users/{userId}
and I decide to move userId to a header parameter because it is considered senstive data what should the URL now become?
It could be /users/ or /users/user
I could then have /users/fees or /users/user/fees
/users/user seems to be more explicit and so better.  What do people think?

How is the public identifier of your user considered sensitive data? This sounds like an XY problem where the true source of the issue is that you're using sensitive data as a public identifier in the first place, and the solution here isn't to hide it but rather to pick a better public identifier in the first place.

its probably an email or username

lets say it's an email.  there is a requirement to be able to look-up using sensitive data.

the usual reason is that the urls are logged

I would change to a POST if the Url isn't going to be unique per resource. Just to avoid any potential caching issues, and send the parameter in the body.
Then You can make the Url /GetUserById or whatever RPC style you like to avoid clashes with your other resource style routes

Something else to consider is whether the user Id is necessary at all. If /users/userId/fees is only ever called with the userId of the current user, then omit the parameter. Have the backend infer the user Id based on the user session.

Or pull the userId from a JWT, which should be safe since it is encrypted.

I'm not suggesting that an API should always be 100% pure REST, but "don't use REST" doesn't seem to really answer the question on what the REST URL taxonomy should be.

@Flater what do you mean, post calls are 100% rest

this problem exists in a few areas for us, we've already agreed to use the header.

REST doesn't care what spelling conventions you use for your resource identifiers (servers controlling their own resource space is part of the point).
If you are taking information that is part of the logical identifier for a resource, and moving it to a separate header, then you are already violating an important REST constraint:

REST is defined by four interface constraints: identification of resources.... -- Fielding, 2000

So what REST wants really doesn't matter anyway.


what should the URL now become?

Since REST doesn't care, and the machines don't care, you can choose any spelling that makes life easier for the people you care about (operators reading the logs, or writers documenting your API, or customers writing clients that talk to your API....
